# Reversing generic class views URL based on <form> GET

Tags: django

I have a generic class view defined as:

```py
class ItemDetailView(DetailView):
    model           = Item
    template_name   = "item_detail.html"
```

with its corresponding URL pattern

```py
('^/item/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', ItemDetailView.as_view(), name="item-detail"),
```

I would like to use something like this in my template

```html
<form method="GET" action="{% url item-detail %}">
    <input type="text" name="pk">
</form>
```

Obviously, `{% url %}` fails because `item-detail` expects `pk` as an argument. Is there any way of calling `ItemDetailView` without having to use a helper view like the one below?:

```py
def get_item_detail(request):
    return reverse('item-detail', kwargs={'pk': request.GET['pk']})
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your template to this:

```
{% load url from future %}
<form method="GET" action="{% url 'item-detail' pk=item.pk %}">
    <input type="text" name="pk">
</form>
```

Here are the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/templates/builtins/#url) for this.

Comment: I may have not explained my question properly. Based on your answer, what I am looking for is to use the GET value of `<input>` as the argument for the `item-detail` view. `item.pk` is not in the context of my template, so I cannot use it. Thanks!

Comment: The whole purpose of the context is to pass variables to template. If you need to pass some item to context from `request.GET`, you can modify the `get_context_data` method.